# Changing output directory for angular cli files

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm trying to serve `inline.bundle.js`, `main.bundle.js`, `polyfills.bundle.js`, `styles.bundle.css`, and `vendor.bundle.js` from `/assets` rather then the root of the dist folder. I can change the url requested in `index.html` by adding `"deployUrl": "/assets",` to my `.angular-cli.json` file, but the files are still output to the root of the dist folder.

How can I change the output folder of those files to be output into `/assets`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the "outDir"?

```
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      ...
```

Comment: I tried this but it sets the output directory for ALL files. So index.html, favicon.ico and even my assets folder end up in dist/assets. (so all my assets are in dist/assets/assets)

Comment: I see. I don't think that there is a way to separate different parts of the output into different folders. You may want to post an issue/question to the github repo for the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just adding a `mv dist/*.bundle.js* dist/assets` to build in my package.json. And `mv dist/*.bundle.css* dist/assets && mv dist/*.bundle.js* dist/asse` for prod.

Comment: How does angular know where those files were moved to?

Answer (score -1):

try modifiying webpack config as follow

```
 output: {
    path: __dirname,   
    filename: 'assets/bundle.js', // move the bundle.js file under the assets folder
 }
```

for your css, if you are using extractTextPlugin, you can specify  css output :

```
new ExtractTextPlugin('./assets/bundle.css'), // bundle.css will be put under /dist/css/
```